Is it possible to modify the background of a SwiftUI table cell?
I'm using Table/TableColumn in a macOS app windowgroup but I seem to be unable to manipulate the background of the complete table column cell, rather only able to manipulate the view that is in the table column cell, which is not terribly useful.
Here is the code that I have, which doesn't give me the affect I'm after:
 TableColumn("Flag") { (lap: Lap) in
   Text("\(lap.lapFlag)")
     .lapFlagEffect(lap.flagStatus)
 }
 .width(ideal: 25)

Which gives this (expected, tho undesirable) effect:

Is it really not possible to modify the background of the entire cell view, not just the content view?  It seems the TableColumn allowable modifiers is quite limited, but not sure if I'm perhaps trying to apply them correctly or if there is a different way I can't seem to locate via search or Xcode code completion.
 TableColumn("Lap Time") { (lap: Lap) in
   Text("\(lap.lapTime)")
 }
 .width(ideal: 25)
 .lapFlagEffect(lap.flagStatus) // <-- not allowed


you could try this approach using a particular frame size and padding if required, to cover more of the cell with the desired color background.
 TableColumn("Flag") { (lap: Lap) in
   Text("\(lap.lapFlag)")
     .padding(10)
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
     .background(Color.green)
 }


Thanks, that's certainly better than my approach for sure.  But the table cell still has its padding that I can't seem to eliminate.  I guess I'm off to iterate on a Grid.
